# Link custom math library in C

Tags: c, windows, math, mingw-w64

I'm trying to run a C program (`main.c`) with an external math library `libmcs` (https://essr.esa.int/project/libmcs-mathematical-library-for-critical-systems), which has been compiled using MinGW compiler (version gcc-6.3.0).

I tried these commands:

```
gcc -o main_libm.exe main.c -lm
gcc -o main_libmcs.exe main.c -LC:\..\libmcs\bin -lmcs
```

They both are compiled, however I am pretty sure that the second application `main_libmcs.exe` is still linked to the default C math library (because the results of the applications is exactly the same, where I was instead expecting numerical approximations differences).

From a research online I have understood that the math library is automatically linked even without declaring `-lm`, and that the option `-nostdlib` allows to disable the automatic linking.

However when I add this option, while linking the external math library:

```
gcc -nostdlib test_mathlib.o -LC:\..\libmcs\bin -lmcs -lc
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `__main'
```

This is because I have to declare the linking option to the standard libraries I have disabled. But then when I try to add the option `-lgcc`:

```
gcc -nostdlib test_mathlib.o -LC:\..\libmcs\bin -lmcs -lc -lgcc
```

I get this error:

```
In function `__do_global_ctors': ... undefined reference to `atexit'
```

So I guess there are more library links which are missing.

At this point I have the following questions:

1. Is there an option to **disable or replace the automatic link only to the default C math library**?
2. In case there isn't, is which are the remaining library links to add when I use the option `-nostdlib`?

Here's the platform details:

```
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

Comment: Use `gcc -v` (plus the ordinary options you'd use) to create a program without your library.  Observe which files it links — there'll be a surprising number, probably.  Then simulate the relevant portions of what you see for your program with the custom library.  Telling the compiler `-nostldib` and then trying to link the standard libraries anyway seems self-contradictory in many ways.

Comment: The path `C:\..\libmcs\bin` puzzles me — my Unix-addled brain thinks there isn't a directory above ```C:\``` so the ```..\``` probably doesn't do anything.  (I did once work with a system called 'Newcastle Connection' that did network access by using `/../other-machine/path/to/file`, but that was a long time ago!)

Comment: If there is a static library you could use `-l:libmcs.a` on the linker command line to link it. I don't think `gcc` recognizes the `-l:name` form, but `ld` does. You may also need to compile with `-fno-builtin` to avoid built-in functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Perhaps OP meant `C:..\libmcs\bin`, but using relative paths on a different drive letter is probably asking for trouble! Still, it would be interesting to know if either path actually exists.

Comment: @IanAbbott — that's a possibility I thought of, but I was mostly pointing out "it isn't clear (to at least some people) what that path means".

Comment: Expectations are not enough. Try to run the application in a debugger, and step into math function. That will tell you for sure which one is linked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the path I used is the one pointing towards the library folder (in my case I used the option `LC:\Software\1_Others\libmcs\bin`). Using the `-v` option I get many libraries but NOT `-lm`, so I don't get how the compiler knows where to get the mathematical function.

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried with `-l:libmcs.a` option and it correctly links the static library (I can see it in the linked library when using `-v` option), however it still doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that I want to **replace** the default `math.h` header with the one contained in my library

Comment: To replace `<math.h>` you can use the `-I` or possibly the `-isystem` option to specify the directory containing the replacement `<math.h>`.